# How to see what field is used as router field in an existing Solr collection?

Tags: solr

Is it stored anywhere in collection configurations? Seems like it's a rather critical piece of a collection config, still cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this info is stored in zookeeper. Look in /collections/the_collection/state.json and you will see something like:

```
 "router":{"name":"compositeId"},
```

or similar.

Comment: The question remains. If I created a collection using `router.field=abc`, how do I look up what it was?

Comment: Isn't that what the answer describes? It's in the `state.json` file present in each collection, stored under Zookeeper.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Solr Admin Web UI, Cloud -> Collections -> YourCollectionName -> state.json

If you don't see router.field there, that means it's using unique document key (default setting).

[image]